# Difference between using a fact and adding it as a simplification rule

Tags: isabelle

Consider proving:

```
(∑ m<k. 2^m) = (∑ m≤k-1. 2^m)
```

where

```
k ≥ 1
```

I found a way to prove it by:

```
  apply(rule sum.cong) 
  using ‹k ≥ 1› by auto
```

But I know that it is not considered good style to mix apply and isar commands. So I try to change to:

```
apply(rule sum.cong,auto simp add: ‹k ≥ 1›)
```

Now this doesn't work. Since this is a common situation, is there an elegant way to do this proof fully in apply style/isar style? What makes the keyword `using` that is fundamentally different from simplication?

Comment: I am not an expert on style, but I believe that `apply(rule sum.cong) using ‹k ≥ 1› by auto` is reasonably idiomatic. There are many proofs in HOL that use this pattern. For example, see `infinite_descent0` from the theory `Nat`. Of course, you could also use `by (rule sum.cong, insert ‹k ≥ 1›) auto`, but I do not believe that there is a substantial difference.

Comment: You can also use: `using ‹k ≥ 1› by (auto intro: sum.cong)` or `using ‹k ≥ 1› by (intro sum.cong) auto` or `by (rule sum.cong) (use ‹k ≥ 1› in auto)`

Comment: could you do `lemma mylemma: assumes "k ≥ 1" shows "(∑ m<k. 2^m) = (∑ m≤k-1. 2^m)" using assms by auto` ?